# how to pass array data to existing jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the below code in which I am clearing the data inside datatable. And now I need to attach a new data to existing datatable.

```
var dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable();
dataTable.clear().draw();

var dtt = $('#mytable').DataTable({
    "aaData": GlobalTable,
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    "columns": [
        {"data": "name"},
        {"data": "position"},
        {"data": "office"},
        {"data": "extn"},
        {"data": "start_date"},
        {"data": "end_date"},
        {"data": "salary"}
    ]
});
```

What should I use? It is giving me error Reinitialize is not allowed for the datatable.

Comment: which jquery library you're using for DataTable? where is DataTable() func is defined?

Comment: I am using "jquery.dataTables.min.js"

Comment: okay, how did you reassign data to your existing datatable?

Comment: That also I have to do, I am still searching for that

Comment: do you want to append more data into your existing datatable or want to empty it first and then assign new data?

Comment: I am clearing it and then filling with an array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110519/discussion-between-puneet-2696717-and-jitendra-pancholi).

Answer (score 0):

You need to `destroy` the table initialization and then `recreate` with new data.

```
// Destroy dataTable
$('#mytable').DataTable().destroy();

// Remove DOM elements
$('#mytable').empty();
```

Now recreate your table with new data.

Comment: Error occured: "DataTable.destroy is not a function"

Comment: var table = $('#mytable').DataTable();
                    table.destroy();
This worked for me....

Comment: @Puneet_2696717 I edited my syntax it should have been `$('#mytable').DataTable().destroy();` I had missed the `()` after `DataTable` while typing

Comment: I have data like inside GlobalTable : t[129] that means it consists of - [0 … 99] [100 … 128]

Comment: @Puneet_2696717 Ok, But whats the point of bringing up that info here.

Comment: Actually after filtering data in Datatable I have ReBind the old data again. But I have used like this: 
`$('#mytable').DataTable();
            GlobalTable = $('#mytable').DataTable();
            GlobalTable = GlobalTable.data();`

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataTab = $("#someTable").dataTable();
```

Clear the table : `dataTab.fnClearTable();`

Redraw the table : `dataTab.fnDraw();`

Add new data to the table : `dataTab.fnAddData();`

Comment: I have data like inside GlobalTable : t[129]
that means it consists of -
[0 … 99]
[100 … 128]

Comment: I am not sure what your exact problem is. Can you please put your code before and after wanting to add new data to the datatable, on jsfiddle ?

Comment: Nikhilesh K V Actually the problem is I cannot copy paste the full code. I am trying this:  
`table.clear().draw();

                    for (i = 0; i < GlobalTab.toArray().length; i++) {
                        table.row.add(GlobalTab.toArray()[i]);
                    }                  
                    table.draw();`

Comment: So now the problem is **GlobalTab.toArray().length** this returns correct number of rows, but when I add this Array data to **table** it doesnt add proper number of rows.